# xcode deletes my data file on every run

Tags: ios, xcode, sandbox

I have an app that edits and saves a data file in the sandboxes Documents directory.

However on every new build and run of the app, it deletes my file and give me a blank one.

How do I tell Xcode not to clear the documents directory?

I hope this behavior does not happen when a user updates their app or else I'm in hot water.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: For some reason since I asked this question, now it isn't deleting the file.... This behavior is strange. I didn't clear the cache or reset the content and settings. Bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Im stupid, I was killing the app (from xcode) before tapping the home button, which in my app saves the data... errrr

If I tap the home button before quitting the simulator it now saves and reads OK

...In the sandbox, it only seemed like it was blank because I only ran it a few times and never initially saved the data.